# Drupal/Drush: How to bundle a project.profile within a project.make?

Tags: drupal, drush, drupal-distributions

Is there any way to do:

```
files["project.profile"][subdir] = "profiles/project"
```

so I get packed the installation profile on the final bundle?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great page about Profiles and Drush make.

http://drupal.org/node/642116

Currently experimenting with this myself.